# Late 2006 iMac without OS: How do I boot to reinstall?

Tags: imac, install, macos

I was given a late 2006 iMac with the hard drives erased and no OS loaded. The iMac boots to flashing folder. I purchased a Mac OS Tiger Install DVD but it is not bootable. I also have a Mac OS Leopard Drop-in DVD that will boot to the installation menu but will not install because 10.4 is not found on the HD.

I have a MacBook Pro with Yosemite loaded and purchased a Thunderbolt to Firewire adapter and Firewire 800 to 400 cable to connect to the iMac. I put the iMac in Target Disk Mode and partitioned the HD into two partitions and copied the Mac OS Tiger install DVD to partition 1. On the MBP in Finder I can see on the iMac the Tiger install DVD loaded onto the partition 1 but in Finder the Install Mac OS has a slash through it. When I double click the Install Mac OS icon I get a pop-up when on the MBP saying Power PC Applications are not supported so I cannot run the Install MAC OS.

Is there some other way to get Mac OS Tiger installed on the iMac since the MBP cannot run the Install Mac OS on the iMac?

Comment: A generic Tiger DVD might be too old for the Machine. The first Intel iMacs shipped with X 10.4.4 By late 06 they would have been shipping initially with 10.4.7, then Leopard by 07. Knowing the exact model would help.

Comment: When you say "isn't bootable" can you tell us what you tried and how you know?

Answer (score 1):

If you Tiger DVD is not bootable it might as well be PowerPC one.

If your iMac is Late 2006 it will support Mac OS X 10.7 as latest.
You can [buy it from Apple for 20$](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion). System requirements for OS X 10.7 is at least 2GB RAM though. So you might check first if you have enough. [These are guides on how to get to the memory](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iMac_Intel).

Then you will need USB pen drive and [Lion Disk Maker](http://liondiskmaker.com) to make it bootable out of bought file.

The mac will accept 2 or 3GB of DDR2-667 SODIMM RAM total(depending on exact model).

Answer (score -1):

2006 is the year when Apple switched from PowerPC CPUs to Intel CPUs, so you've probably got a PowerPC MacOSX Tiger Installer. (which cannot run on Intel MBPs)

If you cannot boot the installer disc from iMac, then your iMac is probably also Intel. You may be in luck getting a OSX 10.6 or 10.7 running on it depending on it's hardware capability, and you don't have to worry about the architecture because all post-10.6 OSXs are Intel.